# Invoke `racket` in a Racket script

Tags: testing, automated-tests, racket, dynamic-compilation

**General question:**

Can I invoke the current `racket` executable from within a running Racket script?

Basically, I'd like a replacement for `(system "racket ...")` in the case that `(find-executable-path "racket")` does not return a path to the Racket executable I'm currently using.

**Context:**

What I really want is to try compiling a few expressions and assert that they raise compilation errors. This is for unit testing.

Comment: BTW, I know Typed Racket solves this problem, but I don't understand the solution. (What is `dr` [here](https://github.com/racket/typed-racket/blob/master/typed-racket-test/main.rkt#L66)?)

Comment: Dear past Ben, you would have liked `find-console-bin-dir` and `find-exe`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you need to step outside of the executable here. Try this:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/modread)

;; define a namespace anchor to attach a namespace to:
(define-namespace-anchor anchor)
;; define a namespace for expansion:
(define target-namespace (namespace-anchor->namespace anchor))

(define program-to-compile
  "#lang racket
(+ 3 4)")

;; go ahead and expand
(with-module-reading-parameterization
 (λ()
   (parameterize ([current-namespace target-namespace])
   (expand
    (read-syntax
     "bogus-filename"
     (open-input-string program-to-compile))))))
```

I think I'm correct when I say that Racket is singularly clean in its ability to provide the compiler to running programs in a disciplined way.

Comment: FWIW, Leif's answer is higher-level than mine, and probably closer to what you want!

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is just to compile some racket expressions, you can do that just with either [`compile`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=compile#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._compile%29%29) or [`compile-syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=compile#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._compile-syntax%29%29). An example file would be:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)

(define tests
  (list #'(+ 1 "3")
        #'(void void)
        #'(string-append 4)))

(for/list ([t (in-list test)])
  (check-exn exn:fail?
     (lambda () (compile t))))
```

Where `exn:fail?` is whatever exception you are looking for.

Furthermore, if you have some common syntax context you want to run your test in, you can use `` #` `` `#,`. So your code would end up something like this:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit)

(define tests
  (list #'(+ 1 "3")
        #'(void void)
        #'(string-append 4)))

(for/list ([t (in-list test)])
  (check-exn exn:fail?
     (lambda () (compile #`(module anonymous racket
                             #,t)))))
```

Finally, if your code is stored on your computer, you can use John's solution, while using [`file->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=file-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3estring%29%29) to convert the file into a string.

Comment: What if my `tests` are in separate files? Can I call `compile` on a filename or port?

Answer (score 2):

For small tests, you can also use [`convert-compile-time-error`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/macro-testing.html?#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fmacro-testing..rkt%29._convert-compile-time-error%29%29) from the `syntax/macro-testing` library. It turns an expression that causes a compile-time error into an expression that raises a run-time error when evaluated. The expression uses the environment where it occurs in the module, including local bindings; you don't have to fiddle with namespaces and `eval`.

```
(check-exn #rx"bad syntax"
            (lambda () (convert-compile-time-error (lambda))))
```

There's also `convert-syntax-error` (on the same page).